# Change VMWare Shared Folder Permission

Tags: 20.04, permissions, vmware-workstation

I have a Ubuntu guest on a Win10 host.  I shared a host directory using VMWare's `Shared Folder` feature (`/mnt/hgfs/HostData`) and that works great.  What I'd like to do is change the owner and set permissions on that folder.

I added the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
.host:/ /mnt/hgfs/ fuse.vmhgfs-fuse uid=33,gid=33,umask=007 0 0
```

However, **when I boot up the shared folder has the default permissions** (drwxrwxrwx root root).  I can get the desired permissions by unmounting and running the fstab file:

```
umount /mnt/hgfs/
mount -a
```

My assumption is that VMWare is mounting the folder elsewhere and it is taking priority, but I don't know where to make changes (or if my assumption is incorrect).  I'm completely new to Linux, so feel free to assume I've made a very basic mistake.

**Update**

I attempted to mount to a new directory (rather than the one VMWare uses):

```
.host:/HostData /mnt/hostdata fuse.vmhgfs-fuse uid=33,gid=33,umask=0007 0 0
```

This results in a weird state when first booted: The permissions are listed as `d?????????`.  `umount` then `mount -a` gets the desired results.  This leads me to believe that the `fstab` file is executed before VMware has the shared folder ready.

Comment: Does [this](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Problem-with-VMWare-Shared-Folders-Permissions-on-Linux-Mint/m-p/2695931/highlight/true#M166371) helps you?

Comment: That might suffice, I'll give it a shot @NicolasFormichella

Comment: See update @NicolasFormichella

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on my original goal of modifying the permissions of the mount point that VMWare creates.  Instead (as suggested by @NicholasFomichella) I'm creating a new mount point which seems to give me the desired results.  The following line what I ended up with in `/etc/fstab`:

```
.host:/HostData /mnt/hostdata fuse.vmhgfs-fuse allow_other,uid=33,gid=33,umask=0007 0 0
```

Note that is fails without `allow_other` as an option.